# app crashed due to UICollectionViewController can't be presentingViewController

Tags: swift, presentviewcontroller

My App is crashed when I try to call Custom UIPresentationController from UICollectionViewController

```
@IBAction func showSettingsMenu(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let mvc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(Constants.SettingsViewControllerId) as? SettingsViewController {        
    mvc.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
    mvc.transitioningDelegate = self
    presentViewController(mvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

here is my Custom Presentation View Controller:

```
class SpecialSizePresentationController: UIPresentationController {
    override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
        guard let height = containerView?.bounds.height else {
            return CGRectZero
        }

        guard let width = containerView?.bounds.width else {
            return CGRectZero
        }
        let y = height * 0.6
        let frameHeight = height * 0.4

        return CGRectMake(8, y - 8 , width - 8 - 8 , frameHeight)
    }
}
```

here is UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol implementation in my UICollectionViewController:

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented:   UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {        
     return SpecialSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
```

and app is crashed in return place with error (due to presenting is nil):

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Is it possible to present custom Presentation Controller from UICollectionViewController?

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, using `source` instaed of `presenting` and error was gone